# Delete or Get all the data with specific name tag in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

```
Table 1: products: id, title, publish,created_at
Table 2: tags: id,name,lang,created_at
Table 3: taggable: id,tag_id,taggable_type,taggable_id
```

In product model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
}
```

I create a new record (in `tags` table)

```
$cat = Category::find(1);
$tag = \App\Tag::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'key1']);
```

Now I save related data in `taggables` table:

```
$cat = Category::find(1);
$cat->tags()->save($tag);
```

It works.

Now I want delete all record for $cat in the taggables:

```
$cat->tags()->detach();
```

It works.

Now,in `taggables` table,I do not have any related data for 'key1' in `tags` table. So I want delete it.

**The Questions:**

How can I check that record (name = 'key1') in `tags` has not any related record in `taggable` and how can I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sql query to delete the data with related id from 2 Table :

```
delete taggable,tags from taggable left join tags on taggable.tag_id= tags.id where tags.id = "which id you want to delete";
```